# How to get the input tag in several div tag with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this :

```
<div class="div1">
 <div class="div2">
  <div class="div3">
   <div>
    <input></input>
   </div>
   <input></input>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the input tag with JQuery and use Css.

I tried this :

```
   $('.div1 :input').css('background-color','blue');
```

but it doesn't work.

The problem is that there is an other input tag?

**Edit** : 
Sorry for not having detailed.
I use a Date Control Form from Nintex and his input tag already has css by default. Problem solved!

Comment: `input` elements are self-closing so your html is invalid.

Comment: Can you please clarify this: `"The problem is that there is another input tag?"`? What is the actual problem?

Comment: It is working fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3LftU/1/ what is the exact problem?

Comment: I want to get the first input tag, not the second.

Comment: @V31 I see it is working! But not for me.

Comment: Just use `first()` or `:first`. Added answer below with examples

Comment: Ok the problem is that I use a Date Control Form from Nintex and his input tag already has css.

Comment: As we are generally not psychic, it would be nice to tell us about *custom controls* and associated *custom styling*, and provide the *actual HTML from your page*! Please provide these things so we can give correct working answers :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have updated, via comment, that you just want the *first* input, use either the first() method on the search result, or use the `:first` selector. Examples of both below:

```
$('.div1 :input').first().css('background-color','blue');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3LftU/2/

or

```
$('.div1 :input:first').css('background-color','blue');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3LftU/3/

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment that a plugin has an input field whose css you want to change which already is their, you can do something like this

```
$('.div1 :input').style('background-color','blue','important');
```